# How to preserve the active state of my 'popup' when a video is played within the 'popup'?

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transitions

apologies for the slightly confusing title, I didn't know how to word it haha! 
The issue I'm having is that I have boxes that when clicked expand so the user can read them. That's all well and good, however, when I add a youtube video to inside a box, and click play, the box fades out like it would if I clicked outside the box. I can click on the text inside the box and it remains. You can find my code along with a JSFiddle below.

I want the box to remain open when the youtube video is played (the embedded iFrame). Does anyone know how I could manage this?

Currently my code is all HTML and CSS, but I'm open to suggestions, I'm just not so familiar with jQuery!

**JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hnaeaxge/1/**

**Here is my code:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:300,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,700,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<style>
html 
  color: #e5e5e5;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Roboto", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

body {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 0 100px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.description {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: rgba(229, 229, 229, 0.7);
}

div, img, footer {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Roboto Condensed", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 36pt;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 24pt;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 18pt;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 16pt;
}

h5 {
  font-size: 14pt;
}

h6 {
  font-size: 12pt;
}

p {
  font-size: 12pt;
  margin-bottom: 12pt;
  margin-right: 12px;
  margin-left: 12px;

}

strong {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: "Roboto Condensed", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #e5e5e5;
}

a {
  -webkit-transition: color 0.25s ease-in-out;
  transition: color 0.25s ease-in-out;
  font-family: "Roboto Condensed", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #dff3fd;
}
a:visited {
  color: #dff3fd;
}
li.active a, a:hover, a:active {
  color: #e5e5e5;
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: -100px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.centered-y {
  position: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.distribution-map {
  position: relative;
  width: 1190px;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.distribution-map > img {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.distribution-map .map-point {
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  z-index: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80);
  opacity: 0.8;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, width 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, z-index 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s; 
  -o-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, width 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, z-index 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s; 
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out, width 0.25s ease-in-out, height 0.25s ease-in-out, z-index 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.25s, 0.25s, 0.25s, 0.25s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, width 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, z-index 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s;
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, width 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, z-index 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s; 
  background: rgba(26, 26, 26, 0.85);
  border: 3px solid #dff3fd;
}
.distribution-map .map-point .content {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out; 
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  overflow: overlay;
}
.distribution-map .map-point:active, .distribution-map .map-point:focus {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 0;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(enabled=false);
  opacity: 1;
  width: 550px;
  height: 400px;
  color: #e5e5e5;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out, width 0.25s ease-in-out, height 0.25s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out, width 0.25s ease-in-out, height 0.25s ease-in-out; 
}
.distribution-map .map-point:active .content, .distribution-map .map-point:focus .content {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(enabled=false);
  opacity: 1;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out, overflow 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out, overflow 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out, height 0.25s ease-in-out, overflow 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.25s, 0s, 0s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out, overflow 0.25s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out, overflow 0.25s ease-in-out;
  overflow: hidden; 
}
.distribution-map .map-point:active .content a:hover, .distribution-map .map-point:active .content a:active, .distribution-map .map-point:focus .content a:hover, .distribution-map .map-point:focus .content a:active {
  color: #dff3fd;
}
        </style>
 </head>
<body>
<h1></h1>
<div class="distribution-map">


    <button class="map-point" style="top:24%;left:26.5%">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="centered-y">
                <h2>Another</h2>
                <p>details</p>
              <iframe width="350" height="197" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5MgBikgcWnY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </button>
    <button class="map-point" style="top:26%;left:49%">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="centered-y">
                <h2>Another</h2>
                <p>Details...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </button>
   <button class="map-point" style="top:27.3%;left:71.4%">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="centered-y">
                <h2>Another</h2>
                <p>Details...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </button>
    <button class="map-point" style="top:63.5%;left:31.5%">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="centered-y">
                <h2>Another one</h2>
                <p>Details...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </button>
    <button class="map-point" style="top:65%;left:56%">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="centered-y">
                <h2>another one</h2>
                <p>Details...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </button>
     <button class="map-point" style="top:68%;left:74%">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="centered-y">
                <h2>Another</h2>
                <p>Details...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: you will need more than just html and css.  when you click the video, the `iframe` gets the focus and takes it from `.map-point` and so your opacity reverts back.  you would need to be able to style `.map-point` based on `iframe:focus` and that's just not possible because there are no parent selectors in css.

Comment: I would suggest just using Colorbox.  a jquery lightbox that is very easy to  customize and make it look exactly as you have it now if you want.

Comment: ColorBox doesn't quite achieve what I wan't I'm afraid. Would you know how to do it in jQuery? Cheers @ChrisM

Comment: I do, with Colorbox.  Not sure why you don't think it will achieve what you want.  It is highly customizable.  You can customize the css _and_ the js.  And you can have as many instances of Colorbox in the same webpage as you want

Comment: Just looking at ColorBox and I'm not sure you can add the movable points that, when clicked, enlarge. I may not be correct though. If I'm wrong, how would I be able to set up ColorBox and customise it @ChrisM? Thanks

Comment: what movable points?  nothing in your fiddle moves that I can see.  If you are talking about how each lightbox starts expanding from its corresponding dot, you can imitate that with colorbox.  In the colorbox js, you will see `initialWidth` and `initialHeight`.  Set these to `"0%"` or maybe `"1%"`.   Set `transition:` to `"elastic"`.  This will make the lightbox start "popping up" from a tiny point.  Then use css to position the starting point.

Comment: Okay that sounds good! I'll give it a try:) Thanks again @ChrisM